# How can I group several Tailwind CSS utilities under one modifier?

Tags: tailwind-css, modifier, utilities

I'm using Tailwind's [default breakpoint values](https://v1.tailwindcss.com/#responsive-to-the-core) in a TypeScript + React project compiled with Vite. But I noticed that in my project and on a [section](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#targeting-a-breakpoint-range) of their documentation that both repeated instances of the same modifiers within one element. In the doc's  case `md:`:

> `<img class="h-48 w-full object-cover md:h-full md:w-48" src="/img/building.jpg" alt="Modern building architecture">`

Is there a way to group `h-full` and `w-48` under one `md:` modifier to make certain styles more readable and easier to locate?

#### My Attempted Solution

Using Tailwind's [default color palette](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#default-color-palette) and default breakpoint values, I made "Hello World" take on an orange background and the heaviest available font weight when the screen size is equal to or greater than `sm`'s default minimum width of 640px:

```
<h1 className="sm:bg-orange-500 sm:font-black">Hello World</h1>
```

To reproduce the same result using one instance of the `sm` modifier within the same `<h1>` element, I tried adding curly braces around utility classes grouped together with commas:

```
<h1 className="sm:{bg-orange-500, font-black}">Hello World</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is NOT possible to group several Tailwind classes under a single breakpoint prefix, such as md: or lg:.
If you need to customize your classes in this way, you may want to consider using an alternative tool, such as [WindiCSS](https://github.com/windicss/windicss) or [UnoCSS](https://github.com/unocss/unocss). These tools offer similar functionality to Tailwind, but with additional features and customization options.

Answer (score 1):

i did exactly it i can do `text-[red,md:[green,hover:pink,2xl],xl]` same for bg
import my code into the shortcut

otherwise with unocss you can do lg:(bg-green text-red text-2xl)

my full config : [unocss.config.ts](https://gist.github.com/jojojojojoj5564656465465/30e48dfe94a72e3203787fb17908aba8)

```
[
        /^(font|bg|border|stroke|outline|ring|divide|text)-\[(.*)\]$/,
        ([, category, stringElement]) => {
            type Category = 'font' | 'bg' | 'border' | 'stroke' | 'outline' | 'text' | 'ring' | 'divide'
            type MediaQuery = 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg' | 'xl' | '2xl'
            const categories: readonly Category[] = ['font', 'bg', 'border', 'stroke', 'outline', 'text', 'ring', 'divide']
            const mediaQuery: readonly MediaQuery[] = ['sm', 'md', 'lg', 'xl', '2xl']
            const rulesForBrakets: Record<'open' | 'close', string> = {
                open: '[',
                close: ']'
            }

            if (!categories.includes(category as Category)) {
                throw new Error(`category in not in unocss list config=> ${category}`)
            }

            function splitString(str: string): Set<string> {
                const result = new Set<string>()
                let currentElement = ''
                let parenthesesCount = true
                for (const char of str) {
                    if (char === rulesForBrakets.open) {
                        parenthesesCount = false
                    } else if (char === rulesForBrakets.close) {
                        parenthesesCount = true
                    }
                    if (char === ',' && parenthesesCount === true) {
                        result.add(currentElement.toLowerCase().trim())
                        currentElement = ''
                    } else {
                        currentElement += char.trim()
                    }
                }
                if (currentElement.trim() !== '') {
                    result.add(currentElement.toLowerCase().trim())
                }
                return result
            }

            const arraySet = splitString(stringElement)

            const regexAtribuffy = new RegExp(`([^:]+):\\${rulesForBrakets.open}([^\\]]+)\\${rulesForBrakets.close}$`)
            const mycustomSet = new Set<string>()

            for (const v of arraySet) {
                if (v.includes(':')) {
                    if (v.match(regexAtribuffy)) {
                        const match = v.match(regexAtribuffy)

                        if (match) {
                            const [, md, rest] = match
                            if (!mediaQuery.includes(md as MediaQuery)) {
                                throw new Error('bad media querie')
                            }
                            const [breakpoint] = md.trim().split(':')

                            for (const e of rest.split(',')) {
                                if (e.includes(':')) {
                                    const index: number = e.lastIndexOf(':')
                                    const state = e.slice(0, index)
                                    const css = e.slice(index + 1)
                                    const result = `${breakpoint}:${state}:${category}-${css.trim()}`
                                    mycustomSet.add(result)
                                } else {
                                    mycustomSet.add(`${breakpoint}:${category}-${e.trim()}`)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        const index = v.lastIndexOf(':')
                        const breakpointORstate = v.slice(0, index)
                        const css = v.slice(index + 1)
                        const value = `${breakpointORstate}:${category}-${css.trim()}`
                        mycustomSet.add(value.trim())
                    }
                } else {
                    mycustomSet.add(`${category}-${v.trim()}`)
                }
            }
            return Array.from(mycustomSet).join(' ')
        }
    ],
```